# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6' on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyside6

Windows.

I try to use qt for python
I found instruction: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/quickstart.html
I installed python 3.11 for windows, run pip install pyside6 with success.

But when i try this code:
import PySide6.QtCore
I got this error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6'
Why python not see installed modules?

I try import PySide6.QtCore from python console and from IDLE with same result

I check PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME env variables, it correct

Comment: If you are using pip list, is the module installed?

Comment: No, modules was not installed. I run install again and problem solved. Thank you

Comment: So if you run the installation again my answer was correct? Can you may mark it as the solution? I would really appreciate it =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would generally prefer to uninstall pyside6 again with the following command:

```
pip uninstall pyside6
```

And then i would go with the essentials from pyside6:

```
pip install pyside6-essentials
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using virtual environment ?
   If so maybe its intalled in environment not in gerenral Path - switch interpreter to that env
2. You can check is it installed by: pip show pyside6

Answer (score 0):

I have found from the site https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/quickstart.html
The package name is pyside6 while the one installed under site-packages is
PySide6. This is also valid for PyQt
so the sample should always consider the PySide6  and not pyside6 as it is now.
This is the reason for for the error below
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyside6'

Hope this could help others